# Safe imports of libraries in multiple LESS or SASS stylesheets

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

Use case:
I have main stylesheet - `main.less` and another one for particular section of site - `app.less`.
Also I use Twitter Bootstrap. And for example in `main.less` I have several overrides for bootstrap, and in `app.less` I want to mixin Bootstap class into my own one (lets take - `.clearfix`) - for more DRYness of my code. So I will import `bootstrap.css` in it and mixin needed class. On web-page at first I will include Bootstrap and other libs, then `main.less` and then `app.less`. And that will make overrides in `main.less` cleared, and all becomes to be messy!

How to correctly do such imports? Is it possible at all with any CSS preprocessors, not only LESS?

Comment: Bootstrap (including its Sass ports) is written in such a way that to do anything *other* than simple theming is going to end up with a rather bloated style sheet containing all sorts of selectors you neither want nor use.  You need to be more specific as to your problem, as it is currently way too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is including bootstrap into the less files an option for you, like you do in development?

My approach in SCSS is like that:

- style.scss (doesnt have any own declarations)

  - imports bootstrap.scss first
  - then imports site specific .scss files, which may contain overrides.

By doing that I can fully control the order of the files and therefore the order of declarations in the generated css file.

Of course one has to decide to trade in the ability to let Bootstrap load via CDN when included, but in my case I use a very down narrowed version of Bootstrap anyway.

Comment: Seems like there is no other options except to combine all in one big style.

Comment: In Less, you can do something like `@import (reference) bootstrap.less` which doesn't copy all the styles but just reference them.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is not meant to be used like that. I mean if you use the compiled version, you should not override it. The idea is to use the less files and modify them. The approach which you are using is kinda messy and I think that there is no elegant way. I'll suggest to avoid including of compiled bootstrap.css and checkout the pure less version.

Comment: "Customizing Bootstrap components takes time, but should be straightforward. Look to the source code often and duplicate the selectors you need for your modifications. Placing them after the Bootstrap source makes for easy overriding without complication" Bootstrap homepage. So it is exactly how Bootstrap could be customized, and customizing sources of external libraries sounds for me obscure.